# Error with putting voids into one another (& compiler no getting to code)

Tags: java

so I've been trying to do some simple coding: Moving a blue square with the WASD keys,

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    new MoveWASD();
}

public MoveWASD() 
{
    super("Use-WASD-to-Move");
    setSize(800, 450);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 450);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(Location[0], Location[1], 20, 20);
    System.out.println("PRINTEDs");
}

public class MoveDetection extends Thread implements KeyListener
{




    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) 
    {


               public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
            try
            {


                if(event.getKeyChar() == 'w')
                {
                    Location[1] = Location[1] - 20;
                    Repeat = true;
                }
                else if(event.getKeyChar() == 'd')
                {
                    Location[0] = Location[0] + 20;
                }
                else if(event.getKeyChar() == 's')
                {
                    Location[1] = Location[1] + 20;
                }
                else if (event.getKeyChar() == 'a')
                {
                Location[0] = Location[0] - 20;
                }
                else
                {
                Location[0] = Location[0];
                }

                Thread.sleep(75);
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                break;
            }
            }

        }

    }


}
```

However, a get an error when putting to static voids one into the other, the arrow (up above) points to my two errors: one under **run** which says: 
    Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
and another under the end parenthasis in run(**)** which says:
    Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatements
Also, when I put a "System.out.write() under any "void" under my movedetection class it does not display, which probably means it isn't getting to it...
As I have just begun coding, I have no idea what this means, any help?

Comment: Are you using an IDE with syntax highlighting?

Comment: Using eclipse indigo I believe... does that help?

Comment: Eclipse should show you where the syntax goes wrong with a red marker, move your mouse cursor on the red x and see what it says

Comment: Stop right here. Sit down. Take a deep breath. Take at least 3 **basic** Java tutorials. Then attempt to do this. You miss a lot of basic concept...

Comment: I did: it's posted up there... (from post above)    Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatements  AND:   Syntax error on token "void", @ expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you cannot nest methods in other methods, maybe read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

You need to *call* the method from the other method

```
public void run(KeyEvent event) {
    //do stuff
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)  {
    run(event);
}
```

Perhaps more importantly you have a `while(true)` in an event handler. This will cause the EDT to be blocked causing the GUI to freeze.

I don't see any reason for the `while` loop. The key pressed event will be fired on *each* key press.

Comment: Thanks, it works, although now it does not run anything under class MoveDetection...

Comment: @user2789610. You shouldn't extend `Thread` from `MoveDetection`. You also need to add `MoveDetection` as a `KeyListener` to the appropriate component in your GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a method in a method:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            ...
```

You can't do that. Try removing the `public void run()`

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    while(true) {
            ...
```

Or if you're trying to start a thread (which I suspect you are):

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```